What is the payload premium from an equatorial launch, (as compared with Cape Canaveral) to Geostationary Orbit?
SeaLaunch went to significant expense and effort to launch from sea surface on the equator.
According to Sea Launch; Advantages of equatorial ocean-platform based launches

The need for a "plane change" to the zero degree inclination of
geostationary orbit is eliminated, providing a major extra launch
"boost". This allows 17.5–25% more mass to be launched to
geostationary orbit than the same rocket launched from Cape Canaveral,
which is at 28.5 degrees north latitude.[citation needed]

Is this payload premium true if the plane change is done at the end of the Geosynchronous Transfer Orbit (GTO) or only if the plane change is done by dog leg or in LEO? I understand there is a significant difference between the two strategies.

English SE: dog-leg, dogleg, or dog leg? and a dog's leg


Is this payload premium true if the plane change is done at the end of the Geosynchronous Transfer Orbit (GTO) or only if the plane change is done by dog leg or in LEO?

It is only true for the case of plane change at apogee. The 'premium' becomes much more extreme if the plane change is performed at any other location. Allow me to elaborate.
The delta V required for a plane change is given by the following equation:
$$\Delta v_i = \frac{2~sin\left(\frac{\Delta i}{2}\right)\left(1+e~cos\left(f\right)\right)~n~a}{\sqrt{1-e^2}~cos\left(\omega +f\right)}$$
$\Delta i$ is the inclination change, $e$ is the orbit's eccentricity, $n$ its mean rate, $a$ its semi-major axis, and $f$ its true anomaly. The true anomaly is the angular distance between the orbiting body and the orbit's perigee. The argument of perigee ($\omega$) is the angular distance between the orbit's perigee and some reference plane. If the burn is conducted at the intersection of the initial and final orbital planes, then the sum $\omega + f$ must be equal to zero. Pairing this with the orbital elements of a geostationary transfer orbit and a 200 km perigee altitude gives the following delta V values for different true anomalies.

Not too surprising: the delta V required for a plane change is minimized at the orbits highest point because the orbital velocity is at a minimum.
Now what about this 'premium' business? The typical mission architecture of a geostationary orbit insertion involves the launch vehicle placing the spacecraft on the geostationary transfer orbit and then the spacecraft's own propulsion system must perform the circularization and plane change. To evaluate the payload premium as a function of true anomaly, I will assume the following.

The baseline for comparison will be a single stage rocket with fixed initial mass and placed already in geostationary transfer orbit with 200 km perigee altitude.
The engine has a 400 second specific impulse
Inert Mass is negligible (or at least packaged with payload mass)
28.5 degrees of plane change are required (per a Florida launch).
the 'premium' will be the percent difference between the payload mass available with and without inclination changes.

The rocket equation relates a vehicle mass ratio to delta V:
$$MR=exp\left(\frac{\Delta V}{g_o Isp}\right)$$
Let's define a baseline Mass ratio accounting for just the circularization burn ($MR_1$) and a variable mass ratio accounting for both the circularization and plane-change burns ($MR_2$). If the initial mass is fixed and the inert mass is negligible, then you can express the premium with the following equation.
$$Payload~Premium~ (\%) =100\left(\frac{m_{payload~1}}{m_{payload~2}}-1\right)= 100\left(\frac{MR_2}{MR_1}-1\right)$$
Now we can finally plot this as a function of true anomaly to see the effect of plane changing at different locations in the orbit.

The results show pretty clearly that the 17.5-25% figure in your question is only true for inclination changes at apogee. The 22% I compute is a function of Isp, so that likely accounts for the range of reported values.
Conducting the plane change anywhere else in the orbit requires more delta V and reduces the payload mass for the same initial spacecraft mass (giving a higher premium). Basically, an equatorial launch to GEO gives a 20% payload premium against the most efficient plane change from a Florida launch, but much higher premiums (~250%) against wildly inefficient plane changes.
